# Root or upgrade to 4.4.2 first?

Tags: root-access, rom, ota-update

I've just received a new Android phone (an LG G2 D802 32GB). I haven't put my sim card in, or signed into Google yet. I know there is an OTA to upgrade it from 4.2.2 to 4.4.2.

Should I root the phone and then start setting it up, or is it best to carry out the OTA first?

Comment: It depends on the phone. [edit] your question to let us know which one you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do either way.

The safe method is to update and then [root](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=45692679#post45692679) the phone.

But You can also root and then install the ota update. But ota will fail if you have

1. custom recovery
2. modified any part of the system like removed bloat, xposed, etc

Still there is  a [post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2702007) in XDA to update ota with custom twrp recovery.